# How to explain this issue and what should be the best solution about Symfony serializer/csv decoder

Tags: php, symfony, csv

I am trying to make a simple CSV uploader with contacts and make them as array using Symfony serializer/CSV encoder. The problem is that when i get data from csv and i dump it i get everything fine i think. But when i want to loop over the array to echo email field or try to create new Objects and save them to database i get an error that index 'Email Address' is undefined. How that can be possible, if when i var_dump in a loop and die after first array on the list i see that 'Email Address' field exists.

Link to image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4TW1.jpg

```
 /**
 * @Route("/upload-csv", name="upload")
 */
public function uploadCsv(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = $form->getData();
        $file = $data->getCsv();

        //dump($file);

        $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');

        $cons = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents($file), 'csv');

        foreach ($cons as $con)
        {
            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->setEmail($con['Email Address']);
            $contact->setFirstName($con['First Name']);
            $contact->setLastName($con['Last Name']);            
            $contact->setCountry($data->getCountry());

            $em->persist($contact);
        }

        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('base.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: If your CSV if in UTF8 format. It may contains à BOM. An invisible char which specify it's UTF8 encoded. Try an utf8_decode or save your file without the BOM

Comment: ya, found that there was a problem with encoding, recreated csv file and everything works fine, thank you